# JSON array of array with key to Standard array of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Sorry to ask this question But I can't figure it with many many search I did...

bu when I try pass the json object or JSON.stringify(data) I always have a error said input error

So the script works when I do that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    $("#output").pivotUI([
            { color: 0, shape: "circle"},
            { color: 1, shape: "circle"},
            { color: 1, shape: "circle"},
            { color: 0, shape: "triangle"},
            { color: 0, shape: "triangle"},
            { color: 1, shape: "triangle"}
        ],
        {
            rows: ["color"],
            cols: ["shape"]
        }
    );
});
```

In reality the data came from a Api that return Json
So how I can pass the return of the json object. To this script.

I use ajax to get the data. I verify the return by do a JSON.stringify and alert() the result and is look exactly what I have in this function but I can't figure how to pass it to this script. I understand is suppose be basic but I can't catch...

Comment: None of your examples are JSON, all are Object Arrays.

Comment: Hello Eric, could you be a little more precise with your question? What do you want to achive?

In case I understand you correctly and you just want to parse the array of objects from your first code-block, you'll notice that it isn't actually valid JSON. What you'll need to do is put `"` around the object keys: `{ "key": "value", "color": 0 }`.

Comment: try `JSON.stringify({ data: myarry })` this should return normalised string for the whole object.

Comment: The very basic information needed here to solve the problem can be found from [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON).

Comment: I completely rewrite the question to try be more clear

Comment: You have to show the real case, a function executed at the load of a page isn't related to the question at hands.